# Graph rendering issue on Azure when multiple instance

Tags: caching, azure, azure-web-roles

I have developed chart rendering functionality in my web application and set following setting to store chart image in temp folder as per below

```xml
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="deleteAfterServicing=false;Storage=file;Timeout=20;URL=~/TempCharts/"/>
```

It will work nice when we testing it in one instance only but when we will make more then one instance of web role then some chart rendering in some not, i think this is problem of multiple stack of server (multiple instance).

What is the solution to this for multiple instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you develop the carting by your own, or you are using the ASP.NET chart controls? If you have your own, then you have a chance for success. In the options I see **Storage=file**. What are other options?

Developing for Windows Azure your approach should be to use a [BlobStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx). That way you can change your chart control to store the temporary image files into a [Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179376.aspx). More over, if you have full control over the user control you could make it write to the blob, and render the path to the image in the blob itself.  You can [point your own domain (name it images.mysite.com) the Azure Blob storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee795179.aspx), then make the user control render directly that URL to the client (i.e. http://images.mysite.com/tempcharts/[guid].png).

**EDIT**

When the clarification about using ASP.NET Chart control is made, here are two solutions to successfully run ASP.NET Chart control in Windows Azure:

1. Change config following [this blog post](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/wely/archive/2010/11/08/using-asp-net-chart-control-in-windows-azure.aspx).
2. [Implement your own HttpHandler for the chart](http://visitmix.com/writings/using-the-asp-net-chart-control-with-multiple-web-roles-in-windows-azure).

Comment: I have used asp.net chart control, automatically it will take temp folder to store chart images

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is, but I *presume* your charting component is generating a file and you're attempting to display the rendered chart from that file on subsequent requests.

The problem is highly likely to be that you've generated it on one server and are attempting to display it from another and it won't exist on that machine's local disk.

Ideally, change your implementation to generate and store the chart in Blob storage. You can use Azure Drive to simulate a drive partition in Blob storage which may avoid the need to change your code, but you need to bear in mind that only one VM instance can have write access to an Azure Drive at a time, so you'll need to think carefully about which instance will create the chart in the first place. Maybe on Role Start, you could attempt to mount an Azure Drive for write access and, if successful, generate your chart. It would then be available to other VM's that have mounted the same Azure Drive with read access.

Comment: I would not recommend using Windows Azure Drive, because the Windows Azure Drive can be **Read/Write** mounted by a **single instalce** only! This is definitely not the option to take.

Comment: @astaykov, you'll see that I have indeed brought up the issue that only a single instance can have write access. What's far from clear from the original question is when the chart is rendered and that ideally Blob storage would be used. If the chart was being recreated for every request, each instance would have generated a local copy and I don't think the original behaviour would have been observed. If it is re-rendered on every request, much better to simply stream the data to the caller and not persist it to storage at all. Azure Drive could otherwise minimise code changes.

Comment: Agree, and agree. But as I have a lot of experience with .net user controls in general (which includes charting), I don't see the point of using handler for "pre-generated" charts. It is very often used in asp.net server controls for dynamically generated content. That is why I am 90% sure @Arun is using this handler to display dynamic data on every user request. Well, if request is made with repeating data, the already generated image will be served. But the general case would be - generating image for every request. That is why I don't even mention Azure Drive.

Comment: @Steve i have used asp.net chart control